# Android Google map V2: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I was error facing inflating class fragment while integrating Google Map V2 with my application.

I started with,

1. Got SHA1 hash and created map key for android.
2. Imported google-play-services as library project(with copy to workspace) and added as a reference library.

I have looked into various solutions, but nothing solves my issue. 
Please can anyone hep me on this? Help is really appreciable. Thanks in advance!

```
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.toyota.dealerparking/com.toyota.dealerparking.GMapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:209)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at com.toyota.dealerparking.GMapActivity.onCreate(GMapActivity.java:11)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    ... 11 more
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:401)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    ... 19 more
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.toyota.dealerparking-2.apk]
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:391)
04-07 09:14:56.387: E/AndroidRuntime(13151):    ... 22 more
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.toyota.dealerparking"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.toyota.dealerparking.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.toyota.dealerparking.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.toyota.dealerparking.GMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my-key" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

GMapActivity.java

```
package com.toyota.dealerparking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GMapActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }
}
```

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: change Activity to FragmentActivity and check it.

Answer (score 0):

In your XML file, make sure you've assigned class with the right package name.It might be `class="com.example.yourClassName"`

Answer (score 0):

In your XML try to change

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

by

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```